# Angular 2 profiles and tomcat

Tags: angular, tomcat, spring-boot, profiles

Currently I'm running a backend springboot application and a frontend Angular2 application.

We don't want to change the code when we switch between local/development/acceptance environment, we just want to let our tomcat know which version of deployment we want to use.

For my backend I was able to follow this guide https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/spring-31-profiles-and-tomcat.html

Now I also want to do this for my frontend Angular2 application but I don't really have an idea on how to start or where to look.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using angular-cli? If so you can declare environments in your .angular-cli.json and build different versions of your app using "ng build --environment=production" and others. Of course this only works at compile time. If you want to change the environment after building maybe you could build the angular app for multiple environments and let the servlet serve different angular builds based on the spring profile.

Comment: Yeah I'm currently using angular-cli and declaring my environments. But now I'd like to follow the principle of 'build once, deploy anywhere' but that seems more difficult than it should be with Angular2.

Answer (score 2):

It might not be the best answer, but one way could be this:

1) In your package.json define your different build targets (I have omitted all options except output-path for brevity), that will use different directories for their output:

```
"scripts": {
    "build-prod": "ng build --output-path dist-prod",
    "build-dev": "ng build --output-path dist-dev"
 }
```

2) Let Maven (or your other favorite build tool) build all Angular variants when you build the Servlet. Make sure all variants will be deployed with your servlet.

3) Add configs for your different environments that will add ResourceHandlers for the right path, depending on that environment. I haven't used Springboot yet so here is a Snippet from a regular Spring MVC Java Config:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class DevConfig {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/dist-dev/")
                .resourceChain(true).addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }

}
```

Hope this will help until somebody has a better idea. :-)